# Calling PowerStatus.BatteryChargeStatus.ToString() sometimes returns 0

Tags: c#, battery, power-state, batterymanager

So my method is as follows:

```
PowerStatus powerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus;

if (powerStatus.BatteryChargeStatus != BatteryChargeStatus.NoSystemBattery)
{
    var batteryStatus = powerStatus.BatteryChargeStatus.ToString()
}
```

From my test systems I get a wide variety of results such as:

> High,
>
> Low,
>
> Charging,
>
> High Charging
>
> Low, Charging
>
> Low, Critical

and heres the strange one... 0?

I'd imagine that it has something to do with [BatteryChargeStatus Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.batterychargestatus(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Your battery is flat:)

Comment: Well why don't you examine the actual value being returned, without the ToString()?

Comment: ... that's some brilliant flags values there. Unknown includes all of the other status flags!

Comment: @Rawling I don't understand what you're getting at?

Comment: The value is presumably set by the manufacturer in accordance to Microsoft's specifications, and this particular manufacturer messed up.

Comment: What @Rawling is talking about is that flag-style enums should only have values that are powers of two. So 10 = 2 + 8 = low + charging. But the value 255 is crazy for a flags-style enum - someone at Microsoft made a mistake in specifying that value for "unknown".

Comment: ahh I see. So I guess this value is a manufacturers mistake and there's not a lot I can do about it apart from maybe write something to catch the case when its 0 and assign it to my own string value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They missed one.  From the docs of the underlying [SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) operating system declaration:

> The value is zero if the battery is not being charged and the battery capacity is between low and high

So just make up your own, like:

```
    var status = SystemInformation.PowerStatus.BatteryChargeStatus;
    if (status != BatteryChargeStatus.NoSystemBattery) {
        var batteryStatus = status == 0 ? "Not charging" : status.ToString();
        // etc...
    }
```

Comment: OK, so my comment above about the manufacturer having messed up is in error. This answer makes it clear that the problem is that the enum definition that should reflect the underlying SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS operating system declaration is missing a value. That on top of the underlying flags being very poorly specified - both zero and 255 are stupid values to use for flags.